# Oracle SQL: How to do a hierarchy and for each "leaf" do a select to another table

Tags: oracle, hierarchy

I have two related entities "ESTABELECIMENTO" and "LOCAL_PRESCRICAO" and for each node of the hierarchy of "ESTABELECIMENTO" I want to list the "children" in "LOCAL_PRESCRICAO"...

[image]

You see... I can make the hierarchy to "ESTABELECIMENTO" this way

```
select lpad(' ',2*(level-1)) 
      || estabelecimento.id 
      || ' ' || estabelecimento.nomecompleto
from estabelecimento
where estabelecimento.activo = 1
start with estabelecimento.id = 36
connect by prior estabelecimento.id = estabelecimento.estabelecimetnopaiid
```

But now I want to list every "LOCAL_PRESCRICAO" associated to "ESTABELECIMENTO" and maintain the hierarchy... how can I achieve this?

Comment: When you say "maintain the hierarchy", do you mean the ordering of the results or just the `LEVEL` value and indentation of the results?

Comment: I mean to have the hierarchy from ESTABELECIMENTO and at the same time list the LOCAL_PRESCRICAO rows that are associated to ESTABELECIMENTO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do as you require.

```
WITH e
  AS (SELECT    LPAD (' ', 2 * (LEVEL - 1))
             || estabelecimento.id
             || ' '
             || estabelecimento.nomecompleto
        FROM estabelecimento
       WHERE estabelecimento.activo = 1
       START WITH estabelecimento.id = 36
     CONNECT BY PRIOR estabelecimento.id = estabelecimento.estabelecimetnopaiid)
SELECT e.*,
       lp.*
  FROM e
 INNER JOIN ESTABELECIMENTO_LOCAL_PRESCRICAO elp
    ON (e.id = elp.estabelecimentoid)
 INNER JOIN LOCAL_PRESCRICAO lp
    ON (lp.id = elp.localprescricaoid);
```

It'll return all rows you selected in your hierarchical query along with their corresponding rows from the `LOCAL_PRESCRICAO` table too.

Hope it helps...

EDIT:

My apologies, I overlooked the concatenation of the ID with the other fields.
This should solve the issue.

```
WITH e
  AS (SELECT rownum AS rnum, e_data, id
        FROM (SELECT    LPAD (' ', 2 * (LEVEL - 1))
                     || estabelecimento.id
                     || ' '
                     || estabelecimento.nomecompleto AS e_data,
                     estabelecimento.id AS id
                FROM estabelecimento
               WHERE estabelecimento.activo = 1
               START WITH estabelecimento.id = 36
             CONNECT BY PRIOR estabelecimento.id = estabelecimento.estabelecimetnopaiid))
SELECT e.e_data,
       lp.*
  FROM e
 INNER JOIN ESTABELECIMENTO_LOCAL_PRESCRICAO elp
    ON (e.id = elp.estabelecimentoid)
 INNER JOIN LOCAL_PRESCRICAO lp
    ON (lp.id = elp.localprescricaoid)
 ORDER BY e.rnum;
```

Comment: What is on your "line 13" and what version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production . Line 13 is " ON (e.id = elp.estabelecimentoid) "

Comment: Answer edited to include the order from the hierarchical query.

Comment: I'm afraid it still doesn't respect the order from the hierarchy.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9203/discussion-between-joao-heleno-and-ollie)

Comment: OK, wrap the HC in a select to get the correct rownum, I'll edit again.

Answer (score 0):

Join results of your hierarchical query to 2 other tables using subquery:

```
select lpad(' ',2*(x.level-1))     
              || x.estabelecimentoid      
              || ' ' || x.nomecompleto  
  from (select rownum r, level,
               , estabelecimento.id estabelecimentoid 
               , estabelecimento.nomecompleto nomecompleto
          from estabelecimento 
         where estabelecimento.activo = 1 
         start with estabelecimento.id = 36 
        connect by prior estabelecimento.id = estabelecimento.estabelecimetnopaiid
       ) x, 
       estabelecimento_local_PRESCRICAO elp, local_prescricao lp
 where lp.id = elp.local_prescricao_id 
   and x.estabelecimentoid = elp.estabelecimetnopaiid
order by r; -- to maintain ordering of the result the same as order of rows from 'x' subquery
```